# Keyboard Maestro Calculate Date using Variables

Tags: mac, keyboard

I'm trying to figure out how to add a variable to today's date in Keyboard Maestro. Can anyone help? Here is a screenshot of my current attempt - http://db.tt/RWcGGvE

As an example of what I'm trying to achieve, I want to be able to type '2' into a variable prompt, and have Keyboard Maestro spit out the date of two days from now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a shell script to execute the date command:

date -v +${KMVAR_Required_in_X_Days}d "+%Y-%m-%d"

man date in the Terminal for information on the date command
man strftime in the Terminal for information on the output formats